# Contar substrings dentro de uma string

Tags: delphi

Quero saber quantas vezes parte de uma `string` aparece dentro de um texto, exemplo:

> Na **Microsoft** prioriza-se a qualidade, por isso a **Microsoft** é a
>   melhor.

Quero uma função no qual eu passe dois parâmetros e me retorne quantas vezes o primeiro parâmetro ocorre no segundo.
Algo como:

```
ContarOcorrencias('Microsoft',TextoOriginal)
```

Deve retornar 2 (duas ocorrências da palavra **Microsoft**).

Tenho algumas ideias de como montar a função, mas queria ver se já há algo nativo ou a melhor forma de cria-la.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método [PosEx](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.StrUtils.PosEx), que retorna a posição do índice (baseado em 1, não em 0) que substring inicia, caso não encontre nenhuma substring válida ele retorna zero.

Daí, a implementação seria algo mais ou menos assim:

1. Ocorrencias = 0;
2. Posicao = PosEx(texto);
3. Enquanto Posicao > 0, incrementa Ocorrencias e Posicao = PosEx(subtexto a partir da Posicao + tamanho da palavra buscada);

O algoritmo ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
function Ocorrencias(TextoProcurado: string, Texto: string): integer;
var
  posicao: integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  posicao := PosEx(TextoProcurado, Texto, 1);
  while posicao > 0 do
  begin
    inc(result);
    posicao := PosEx(TextoProcurado, Texto, posicao + length(TextoProcurado));
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var AWord, AText: String;
begin
  AText := 'Na Microsoft prioriza-se a qualidade, por isso a Microsoft é a melhor.';
  AWord := 'Microsoft';
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Ocorrencias: ' + IntToStr(ContarOcorrencias(AWord, AText)));
end;

Function TForm1.ContarOcorrencias(AWord, AText: String): Integer;
var APos: Integer;
    AWordFind: String;
begin
  Result := 0;

  //enquanto o texto tiver texto verifica
  While AText <> '' do
    Begin
      //procuro espaços o próximo espaço " "
      APos := Pos(' ', AText);
      if (APos > 0) then
        begin
          //pego a palavra e apago-a da variável AText
          AWordFind := Trim(AnsiMidStr(AText, 1, APos - 1));
          Delete(AText, 1, APos);
        end
      //quando não encontramos mais " " então pegamos o resto do texto
      else AWordFind := AText;

      if AWordFind = AWord then Result := Result + 1;
    End;
End;
```

Answer (score 1):

Diversas respostas, mas nenhuma simples de resolver.

Declare nas uses `System.RegularExpressions`, depois para usar :

`TRegEx.Matches(TextoOriginal, 'Microsoft').Count`

Dentro da uses que mencionei varias outras funções interessantes!

Comment: Ele não especificou qual versão do `Delphi` estava utilizando, se a que ele estiver usando for `Delphi 7` por exemplo, essa opção não irá funcionar.

Comment: Exatamente por isto ja postei uma resposta mais atualizada, que não utiliza tanto o processador! Como a Tag é `delphi`, não me apeguei em detalhes!

Comment: Só não é necessário menosprezar todas as outras respostas, já que a sua não atende todas possibilidades.

Comment: Não houve menosprezo meu caro, o intuito aqui é sempre responder! E com base base em algo, se desejar seguir o assunto, favor chamar no Chat!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que não tenha nada nativo com este objetivo, mas você pode utilizar a seguinte função:

```
function CountInText(Find, Text: String): Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  while (Pos(Find, Text) > 0) do
    begin
      Text := Copy(Text, 1, Pos(Find, Text) - 1) + Copy(Text, Pos(Find, Text) + Length(Find), Length(Text));
      Inc(Result, 1);
    end;
end;
```